# python-2.7 | SimpleCV - TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an index

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, typeerror, simplecv

**I'm trying to build a Image dewarping tool using simpleCV 
and python2.7**.

The code below worked perfectly fine before(when I was on Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS)
but I recently updated to the Ubuntu 17.04 and I get this error now.

**Here is the function:**

```
def buildMap(Ws, Hs, Wd, Hd, R1, R2, Cx, Cy):
    map_x = np.zeros((Hd, Wd),np.float32)
    map_y = np.zeros((Hd, Wd),np.float32)
    rMap = np.linspace(R1, R1 + (R2 - R1), Hd)
    thetaMap = np.linspace(0, 0 + float(Wd) * 2.0 * np.pi, Wd)
    sinMap = np.sin(thetaMap)
    cosMap = np.cos(thetaMap)

    for y in xrange(0, int(Hd-1)):
        map_x[y] = Cx + rMap[y] * sinMap
        map_y[y] = Cy + rMap[y] * cosMap

    return map_x, map_y
```

and this is the error I get:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "./fy360.py", line 189, in new_dewarp
    xmap, ymap = buildMap(Ws, Hs, Wd, Hd, R1, R2, Cx, Cy)
  File "./fy360.py", line 122, in buildMap
    map_x = np.zeros((Hd, Wd),np.float32)
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an index
```

*what is the problem in my code?*

Comment: because you cant pass index[5.4] and get value you need integer index[1or2] like this

Comment: Either `Hd` or `Wd` passed to this function is a float and not an integer.

Comment: @DanielF , @Exparator  `Hd` and `Wd ` values are `image frame sizes` so approximating them to an integer would compromise accuracy don't you think?

Comment: Image frame sizes in pixels? Those are always integers. What would an image that's 16.5 pixels wide look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `np.zeros` function needs `Hd` and `Wd` to be integers, not floats. Previous versions of Python would silently cast to integer, but newer versions give an error instead. Try adding this:

```
Hd = int(Hd)
Wd = int(Wd)
```

Comment: oh dang, I was under the impression that using float value was more accurate and resulted in better results.